# Editing a query in another DB

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to open a second Access database from within an Access database, and edit a query in that second DB?  I know you can open one Access DB from another, but I'm just not sure whether or not you can edit a query that way.

If it's possible, can anyone show me some sample code to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OpenDatabase` to return a `DAO.Database` reference to your remote database.  Then you can access a saved query via its `QueryDefs` collection.

Here is an example from the Immediate window:

```vb
set db = OpenDatabase("C:\share\Access\Database1.mdb")

Debug.Print db.QueryDefs("Query1").SQL
SELECT dbo_foo.bar, TypeName(bar) AS TypeOfBar
FROM dbo_foo;

db.QueryDefs("Query1").SQL = "SELECT d.bar, TypeName(d.bar) AS TypeOfBar" & vbcrlf & _
    "FROM dbo_foo AS d;"

Debug.Print db.QueryDefs("Query1").SQL
SELECT d.bar, TypeName(d.bar) AS TypeOfBar
FROM dbo_foo AS d;

db.close
```